# Pressing the escape button in Angular makes the website hangs for two seconds

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using Angular and PrimeNG, I have an application and one of the views uses two tables. One table contain 200 row and the other 10 rows.

When I press on escape this is what I get the next stack shown in the screenshot and the site hangs for two seconds.

[image]

The solutions I tried and worked is to listen to the escape button and stop propgation the event HOWEVER this means I have to implment an extra service to handel the deafult escape behavior like: Closing a dialog, closing an overlay, unfocus an input button and so on. THis handeling feels like an extra effort that I would be surprised I would have to do myself for somthing I feel a mistake I made.

Note: changing the detection stratigy did not work!

Comment: Hi, we have the same problem. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @besc not yet, I found a solution that suggests you should listen to the escape globally and prevent its default behavior. It works, but this will make other dialog, overlays, and input stop listening to this event.

Comment: Hi @Alhajras, I've solved my problem. I have a dynamic menu in (PrimeNG  AppMenuitemComponent class) my app. It's a little odd but when I replace [pTooltip] property with title property on a (hyperlink) tags in menu item, problem solved.

I've replaced [pTooltip]="item.label" with title="{{item.label}}"

Comment: yes, that was the issue, in my app I am using lots of `pTooltip` and seems like they listen to escape event.

Answer (score 0):

This is a PrimeNG issue not Angular look here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/issues/12962